# python kivy with plyer app crashes on android (camera)

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I develop kivy application using plyer. Build by buildozer and starting app on android succeeded, but application crashes when I push the button starting a camera, and nothing is output in logcat. I work without a problem when I carry out the same code in kivylauncher. It was similar even if I tested it with an accelerometer.

I think that necessary setting may be short when I build application using plyer.

```
--- source code ---

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from plyer import camera

class UI(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(UI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.lblCam = Label(text="Click to take a picture")
        self.add_widget(self.lblCam)

    def on_touch_down(self, e):
        try:
            print('test')
            camera.take_picture('/storage/sdcard0/example.jpg', self.done)
        except NotImplementedError:
            print("This feature has not yet been implemented for this platform")
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(type(e)))

    def done(self, e):
        self.lblCam.text = e

class Camera(App):
    def build(self):
        ui = UI()
        return ui

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        pass

Camera().run()


 --- buildozer.spec ---
(buildozer android_new debug)

requirements = plyer,kivy,python2
android.permissions = CAMERA
android.api = 22
android.minapi = 21
android.sdk = 22
android.ndk = 13b
android.bootstrap = sdl2

--- environments
buildozer: 0.33dev
android (device)version: 5.0.2

--- adb logcat -s python ---
I/python  (30711): AND: Ran string
I/python  (30711): Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
I/python  (30711): [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 16)
I/python  (30711): [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/data/org.test.cameraapp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-12-15_0.txt
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2-dev0
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, Dec 15 2016, 13:03:19) 
I/python  (30711): [GCC 4.9.x 20150123 (prerelease)]
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 193 symbols loaded
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
I/python  (30711): [ERROR  ] [Input       ] AndroidJoystick is not supported by your version of linux
I/python  (30711): Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python  (30711):   File "/home/kivy/Documents/echizen-cyo/camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/cameraapp/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/input/providers/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
I/python  (30711):   File "/home/kivy/Documents/echizen-cyo/camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/cameraapp/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/input/providers/androidjoystick.py", line 20, in <module>
I/python  (30711): Exception: android lib not found.
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 2.0>
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <ARM>
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Mali-450 MP>
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
I/python  (30711): [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
I/python  (30711): [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
I/python  (30711): [ERROR  ] [Base        ] Could not remove android presplash
I/python  (30711): test
```

I am worried about "Exception: android lib not found.".

Answer (score 0):

This is [bug](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/959) in p4a/pyjnius. You can use old toolchain until it would be fixed.

Comment: Thank you for an answer.

Comment: @asaitoc not at all. I faced with this problem recently: https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/959 I find easiest way is to use old toolchain. Patches from answer didn't help to me.

Comment: The camera succeeded by using old toolchain.
However, I used spataiite in my application, but it has been with an error of symbol not found when I loaded mod_spatialite.so by the application that built in old toolchain.
But I let after trying it, I was all good and strain because the application method of the patch to pyjnius in new toolchain was listed in your link.
Thank you for great advice!

Answer (score 0):

After investigating it, I understood that it crashed in plyer.platform.android.**init**.py.

It seemed to crash in activivity = PythonActivity.mActivity, but was not able to handle the exception.

```
--- plyer.platform.android.__init__.py ---

from os import environ
from jnius import autoclass

ANDROID_VERSION = autoclass('android.os.Build$VERSION')
SDK_INT = ANDROID_VERSION.SDK_INT

print('ANDROID_VERSION = {}'.format(SDK_INT))

if 'PYTHON_SERVICE_ARGUMENT' in environ:
    print('test-1-1')
    PythonService = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonService')
    print('test-1-2')
    activity = PythonService.mService
    print('test-1-3')
else:
    print('test-2-1')
    PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
    print('test-2-2')
    activity = PythonActivity.mActivity
    print('test-2-3')


--- logcat ---

I/python  ( 9384): AND: Ran string
I/python  ( 9384): Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
I/python  ( 9384): [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 16)
I/python  ( 9384): [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
I/python  ( 9384): Purge log fired. Analysing...
I/python  ( 9384): Purge finished!
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/data/org.test.cameraapp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-12-16_0.txt
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2-dev0
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, Dec 16 2016, 19:14:20) 
I/python  ( 9384): [GCC 4.9.x 20150123 (prerelease)]
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 193 symbols loaded
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
I/python  ( 9384): [ERROR  ] [Input       ] AndroidJoystick is not supported by your version of linux
I/python  ( 9384): Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python  ( 9384):   File "/home/kivy/Documents/echizen-cyo/camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/cameraapp/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/input/providers/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
I/python  ( 9384):   File "/home/kivy/Documents/echizen-cyo/camera/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/cameraapp/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/input/providers/androidjoystick.py", line 20, in <module>
I/python  ( 9384): Exception: android lib not found.
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES   2.0>
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <ARM>
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Mali-450 MP>
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
I/python  ( 9384): [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
I/python  ( 9384): [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
I/python  ( 9384): [ERROR  ] [Base        ] Could not remove android presplash
I/python  ( 9384): test
I/python  ( 9384): ANDROID_VERSION = 21
I/python  ( 9384): test-2-1
I/python  ( 9384): test-2-2
```