# How to force buildozer to use old_toolchain of python-for-android?

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I am stuck with a similar problem mentioned in:
[python kivy with plyer app crashes on android (camera)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156449/python-kivy-with-plyer-app-crashes-on-android-camera)
which is related to crash of android application when it uses the camera using python plyer library.

I understood that I can use the old_toolchain of python-for-android since the new master version still has an issue that has not been solved yet.

Running buildozer automatically clones the latest python-for-android master, so **the question is** how to make it clones the old version and use it instead?

I tried to run buildozer as follows:

```
buildozer android_old debug
```

but I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.33', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1058, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 91, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 103, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 212, in build
    self.target.build_package()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 663, in build_package
    self._update_libraries_references(dist_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 857, in _update_libraries_references
    if not content[-1].endswith(u'\n'):
IndexError: list index out of range
```